# Embed Stripe in iframe, redirecttocheckout

Tags: iframe, stripe-payments

I have stripe successfully working in a framework of:
mydomain ,

```
mydomain :call to stripe 
a)stripe :redirecttocheckout  
b)mydomain :success, or 
c)mydomain :cancel
```

Problem:
if i setup another domain with a single landing page / containing an iframe embeding mydomian or using httpaccess. everything works fine up to the point of a), b) or c)
i.e a) redirecttocheckout loads stripe as the main url, and b or c have to be hardcoded the urls. Nb. there could be multiple other domains so hardcoding each entry into the success or cancel is not an option.

i.e

| steps: | processing: | address bar: |
| --- | --- | --- |
| otherdomain | load mydomaininto iframe | otherdomain |
| mydomain | various | otherdomain |
| mydomain | call to stripe | otherdomain |
| stripe | redirecttocheckpout | stripe |
| mydomain | success | mydomain |
| mydomain | cancel | mydomain |

whereas what i would like:

| steps: | processing: | address bar: |
| --- | --- | --- |
| otherdomain | load mydomaininto iframe | otherdomain |
| mydomain | various | otherdomain |
| mydomain | call to stripe | otherdomain |
| stripe | redirecttocheckpout | otherdomain or stripe |
| mydomain | success | otherdomain |
| mydomain | cancel | otherdomain |

1)
if i embed the stripe components into an mydomain.iframe i thought that the redirecttocheckout, success or cancel calls would only post into the iframe and i could manage with that.
however that doesn't appear to be the case as they redirect the main url and are not restricted to the iframe.

2)
As a worst case i can carry the 'otherdomain' as a passed parameter and then in success, cancel pages redirect to the otherdomain, but that would be fairly messy.

I guess the question here is opion 1) above correct in terms of stripe always redirecting the main page vs iframe and secondly is there any other option other than option 2 to consider.

Thanks. M

Comment: You cannot redirect to Stripe Checkout in an iframe. When Checkout is completed, it will redirect to whatever domain/URL you specify in https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-success_url